# deleting cronjob that shouldn't be there

Tags: debian, cron

I installed Froxlor a while back and uninstalled it again, because it didn't fit my need. The server I'm running is a Debian webserver. After inspecting the system log file using:

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

I noticed that there are still some Froxlor things going on.

most noticeable are log entries like:

```
Jun 25 10:55:01 v220200220072109810 CRON[5633]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/nice -n 5 /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/froxlor/scripts/froxlor_master_cronjob.php --tasks 1> /dev/null)
Jun 25 11:00:01 v220200220072109810 CRON[5727]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/nice -n 5 /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/froxlor/scripts/froxlor_master_cronjob.php --tasks 1> /dev/null)
```

However, when inspecting the crontab for the root user, I don't have any active crontabs. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Look at "grep froxlor /etc/cron.d*" to found in the system configuration too

Answer (score 1):

Cron can source its files from several places, so search for froxlor in:

- /etc/crontab
- /etc/cron.d/
- /etc/cron.{hourly,daily,etc}/
- /var/spool/cron/crontabs/

If it's not in root's crontab (/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root) then it's most likely in /etc/cron.d/. It's more common for a package or "make install" process to create a file, rather than edit one, so you'll probably find something like /etc/cron.d/froxlor.